# Converting the kong official docker-compose to deploy in docker swarm mode not working?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, kong

I am trying to write the **docker-compose** file of kong api gateway that I can use to deploy as stack in docker nodes running in docker swarm mode.

> The kong has its own official docker-compose file but unfortunately it
>   is using the version-2.1 and thus I have to remove some features like
>   depends on with conditions.

Bellow is the docker-compose.yml I have written to make it docker stack compatible. ***The problem is, migrations service is not working***

```
version: '3.4'
networks:
 net-kong:
services:  consul:
    image: progrium/consul:latest    networks:
      - net-kong    command: -server -bootstrap -ui-dir /ui    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "curl -I -s -L http://127.0.0.1:8500 || exit 1"]
      interval: 5s
      retries: 10
    ports:
      - 8500:8500
    expose:
      - 53
      - 8300
      - 8301
      - 8302
      - 8400
      - 8500
    dns:
      - 127.0.0.1

  nginx-lb:
    image: nginx:kong
    networks:
      - net-kong
    depends_on:
      - consul
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
      - 8443:8443
      - 8001:8001
      - 8444:8444
    expose:
      - 8000
      - 8443
      - 8001
      - 8444
    links:
      - consul:consul
    command: >
        /bin/containerpilot
        -config file:///etc/containerpilot/containerpilot.json
        nginx -g "daemon off;"

  kong-database:
    image: postgres:9.5
    networks:
      - net-kong
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=kong
      - POSTGRES_DB=kong
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "postgres"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5

  kong-migration:
    image: kong
    networks:
      - net-kong
    depends_on:
      - kong-database
    environment:
      - KONG_DATABASE=postgres
      - KONG_PG_HOST=kong-database
    command: kong migrations up

  kong:
    image: kong
    networks:
      - net-kong
    depends_on:
      - kong-database
      - kong-migration
    environment:
      - KONG_DATABASE=postgres
      - KONG_PG_HOST=kong-database
      - KONG_PG_DATABASE=kong
      - KONG_ADMIN_LISTEN=0.0.0.0:8001
    expose:
      - 8000
      - 8001
      - 8443
      - 8444
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "curl -I -s -L http://127.0.0.1:8000 || exit 1"]
      interval: 5s
      retries: 10
```

> To my understanding it is not working because the migration is trying
>   to run before the database service is running.Which will lead to
>   error. Please guide me on this.

Migrations is not working and even the logs shows nothing when typed.`docker service logs service-name`

Comment: Are you sure that your docker swarm stack deployed successfully?

Comment: Yes its is not deployed successfully and that is my requirement I am trying to write official kong provided composer in 3.4 version to make it stack compatible @RavinduFernando

Comment: I have no previous experience with Kong. Have you posted this on their (Kong) developer forums?